# How is the camera coordinate system in OpenCV oriented?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, triangulation

I'm trying to get the 3D coordinate of a point from the triangulation of two view.
I'm not really sure if my results are correct or not.

For example I'm not really sure if the sign of the coordinates are correct because I'm not sure how the camera frame is oriented.

The z axis positive verse is entering or exiting the image plane?
And x and y? Do they follow the right hand rule?

Thanks in advance for a clarification!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The coordinate system is set according to the image and the description on this [webpage](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT9/node2.html)

[image: The coordinate systems involved in camera calibration]

Comment: So it's a left-handed coordinate with x going right, y going down, z going forward?

Comment: Nope, it's definitely a right-handed coordinate system.