# Stereo calibration based on rotation R and translation T directly instead of using point correspondences

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, stereoscopy

Knowing the rotations and translations of two cameras in world coordinates (relative to some known point), how would I calibrate my stereo system?

In OpenCV the normal approach is to use a calibration pattern in front of both cameras to get point correspondences. These points are used in `stereoCalibrate` which calculates the rotation matrix `R` and translation vector `T` (and the fundamental matrix `F`). In the next step the stereo rectification can be done to row-align images of both cameras with `stereoRectify`. `stereoRectify` needs `R` and `T` to calculate the homographies for the perspective transform of the images and also calculates the `Q`-matrix for translating disparity to depth.

Giving the situation that `R` and `T` in the world coordinate system are already known (known is the rotation around the z-Axis (floor-ceiling or yaw angle in aeronomy) and the rotation around the axis perpendicular to the camera view (pitch angle)), in which coordinate system should they be given to `stereoRectify`? What I mean with that is that there is the coordinate system of Camera1, of Camera2, and the (or one) world coordinate system.

The computation of the essential matrix `E` can be done with `R * S` where `S` is the skew-symmetric matrix of `T` and the fundamental matrix `F` with `M_r.inv().t() * E * M_l.inv()` following LearningOpenCV 3 from Kaehler and Bradski (M_r and M_l are the camera intrinsics of the right and left camera respectively). Here the question on `R` and `T` is the same. Is it the rotation from one camera to the other in world coordinates or e.g. in the coordinate system of one camera?

A sketch of the involved coordinate systems can be found here:
[How is the camera coordinate system in OpenCV oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987465/how-is-the-camera-coordinate-system-in-opencv-oriented), however it is still unclear for me how exactly `R` and `T` should be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not terribly clear, but...

IIUC you know the extrinsic parameters of both cameras, ergo their relative pose, but not the intrinsic ones. Therefore you still need to calibrate the cameras' intrinsics.

Knowing the relative pose of the cameras simply allows you to calibrate the intrinsics of the two cameras independently. Whether this is a simplification for your procedure or not depends on your particular setup.

Note that, unless you have inferred the extrinsics you have from a separate, image-based procedure, you should hardly trust their values - especially if they are derived by some sort of CAD model of your rig. The reason is that, unless your cameras have quite low resolution, pixel-level accuracy is likely to be much finer than what the manufacturing tolerances of your rig would account for.

Comment: I have the intrinsics of both cameras by calibrating both cameras separately. As the baseline of the two cameras is very large, I cannot calibrate them with a calibration pattern and have to rely on the extrinsics measured as good as possible. I am aware of the accuracy problematic.

Comment: You don't actually need a pattern, just several points at known relative locations visible in both cameras. For large baselines you can get creative, e.g. manufacture a triangle with three rods and ping-pong balls at the vertices.