# OpenCV triangulatePoints() getting negative depth, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, triangulation

So the setting is given a coordinate system shown below where the `z`-axis is pointing out of the screen (towards you), the camera focal length is `270` pixels and image resolution is `640x480`, then we have an object somewhere in 3D space, and two drones `d1` and `d2` taking two observations at two different viewpoints, where is `d1` is at `(6, 3, 2)` and the corresponding image coordinate of the object is `(320, 280)`, and that of `d2` is `(9.5, 4.5, 3)` and `(160, 408)`, also the heading of `d1` is `-20` degrees from the `y`-axis and that of `d2` is `+30` degrees from `y`-axis, the goal is to determine `(x, y, z)` where the object is at, the drones are hovering over the `xy` plane

[Click Here for Image Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHI9a.png)

Given the information, by letting `d1` be the reference frame, we can have the camera intrinsics `K = [[270, 0, 320], [0, 270, 240], [0, 0, 1]]`, the transformation is rotate `+50` degrees with `z`-axis as the rotation axis, and translation `t = [3.5, 1.5, 1]`, therefore my code

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def pixel2cam(pt, K):
    u = (pt[0] - K[0][2]) / K[0][0]
    v = (pt[1] - K[1][2]) / K[1][1]
    return np.array([u, v], dtype=np.float32)

def triangulate(points_1, points_2, K, R, t):
    cam_pts_1 = pixel2cam(points_1, K).reshape(2, 1)
    cam_pts_2 = pixel2cam(points_2, K).reshape(2, 1)
    T1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 1, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    T2 = np.hstack((R, t))
    X = cv2.triangulatePoints(T1, T2, cam_pts_1, cam_pts_2)
    X /= X[3]
    return X

K = np.array([[270, 0, 320], [0, 270, 240], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
# rotate +50 degrees along z axis
R = np.array([[0.643, -0.766, 0], [0.766, 0.643, 0], [0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
t = np.array([[3.5], [1.5], [1]], dtype=np.float)

pt_1 = (320, 280)
pt_2 = (160, 408)

X = triangulate(pt_1, pt_2, K, R, t)
```

and that gives you a homogeneous coordinate `X = [[-2.4155867], [ -5.1455526], [-12.032189], [1.]])` where `z` is negative, so my question is

- Did I correctly formulate `R` and `t` here?
- If yes, then could the error be due to a different camera coordinate system used here than that in `OpenCV`?

Any help is appreaciated!

Answer (score 3):

I see multiple issues in your code. I'll try to examine them one by one in the different sections below.

### OpenCV point triangulation

Firstly, the OpenCV `cv2.triangulatePoints()` takes the projection matrix *from world to pixel* coordinates, and the pixel coordinates of your world point on the images. See the `cv2.triangulatePoints()` [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad3fc9a0c82b08df034234979960b778c). You can also read the maths behind OpenCV projection in 'Detailled description' section of [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html).

Here is the corrected version of your `triangulate()` function:

```py
def triangulate(points_1, points_2, K, R, t):
    T1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 1, 0, 0], 
                   [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    T2 = np.hstack((R, t))
    proj1 = np.matmul(K, T1)
    proj2 = np.matmul(K, T2)
    X = cv2.triangulatePoints(proj1, proj2, points_1, points_2)
    X /= X[3]
    return X
```

### Rotation matrix

In OpenCV coordinates system, the z-axis of the camera is the optical axis (see diagram in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022846/13272497)). Doing a rotation around z-axis doesn't match the image you linked in your question, a rotation of -50 degrees around the y-axis seems more correct.

You can recompute your rotation matrix using `cv2.Rodrigues()`. Be aware that this function takes angles in radians, see the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac).

```py
rotation_vector = np.array([0, -50 / 180 * np.pi, 0])
R, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rotation_vector)
```

### Units

You stated that your focal is in pixel units. Looking at the data, I highly doubt that the focal length and translation values are consistent, at least if they are expressed in pixels. I see two possibilities:

- The data is correct but you misinterpreted the unit of the focal length while writing your question. It that case, forgot about the rest of this section;
- The units stated in your question are correct and your are trying to triangulate points using inconsistent data.

To fix that make sure that the focal length and translation are all expressed in pixels or in the same distance unit. You can do the conversion from pixel to distance unit by diving by the pixel pitch of your camera, and do the conversion from distance unit to pixels by multiplying by the pixel pitch. The pixel pitch should be written in the datasheet of the camera model you are using.

### Result

Applying the three corrections described above gives me a `X` vector that have a positive z coordinate. The value I obtain doesn't mean much though, since I am not sure of the correct value and units of the data.